# iOS Crash error indexPath out of bounds when searching in TableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchbar

I have 2 arrays, one is base contains 532 elements and other one is filter array. I have `UISearchBar` which has delegate method

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    self.filter(searchText: searchText)
}

private func filter(searchText: String) {
    if searchText.isEmpty {
        self.filterDelegates = self.delegates
    } else {
        self.filterDelegates = self.delegates.filter {
            $0.delegate.fullName.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        }
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

when I scroll tableview and start searching it crashes, It's not resetting indexPath on `self.tableView.reloadData()` Method

Logs in CellforRow at indexpath

```
INDEXPATH : 23
FILTER COUNT : 396
INDEXPATH : 22
FILTER COUNT : 20


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(
            withIdentifier: DelegateTableViewCell.defaultReuseIdentifier
        ) as! DelegateTableViewCell
        print("INDEXPATH : \(indexPath.row)")
        print("FILTER COUNT : \(self.filterDelegates.count)")
        cell.item = self.filterDelegates[indexPath.row] // Index out of bound
        return cell
    }
```

Also I'm using same filter array for no. of rows method

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.filterDelegates.count
}
```

What's wrong I'm doing?

Comment: `FILTER COUNT : 20`, `INDEXPATH : 22`, `return self.filterDelegates.count` I think this is your problem

Comment: check the index < array.count then access elements, to avoid the crash

Comment: Is there only a single section in your table view?

Comment: @mag_zbc: yes single section

Comment: Don't know it will work or not but you can put that in begin update and end update block

Comment: Can you provide what number is return in numberOfRowsInSection after filtering? It also would clear if it's called before (that should be normal) any call of cellForRowAt method or after.

Comment: @AlexSh.: "NO of rows: 532"
"NO of rows: 272"
After that it crashes typed first alphabet

Comment: @AbhishekThapliyal Does this print "NO of rows: 272"  called before print("INDEXPATH : \(indexPath.row)") with wrong indexPath ?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are saying this happens when table view is scrolling I would kill scrolling inside of the search function like so:

```
private func filter(searchText: String) {
    //force stop the scroll
    tableView.setContentOffset(tableView.contentOffset, animated: false) 

    if searchText.isEmpty {
        self.filterDelegates = self.delegates
    } else {
        self.filterDelegates = self.delegates.filter {
            $0.delegate.fullName.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        }
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Index will still remain same hence it will crash in this case also

Comment: Do you think or you know? I would argue that crash happens because `UITableView` wants to get next cell right at the time when you change its `dataSource` since it is scrolling, if we stop scrolling `UITableView` will not need that next `IndexPath` and thus crash will be averted...However if it still crashes do let me know...

Answer (score 0):

First Scroll Everytime and Then Update.

```
private func filter(searchText: String) {

if searchText.isEmpty {
    self.filterDelegates = self.delegates
} else {
    self.filterDelegates = self.delegates.filter {
        $0.delegate.fullName.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
    }
}

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.3, animations: {
    // animation stuff      
    self.tableView.setContentOffset( CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0), animated: false)

}, completion: { _ in
    // do stuff once animation is complete
    self.tableView.reloadData()

})

}
```

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure, but may be it is main thread issue. Please try to put `self.tableView.reloadData()` in Main thread.Like,

> DispatchQueue.main.async { self.tableView.reloadData() }